# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with stackoverflow issue in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

While calling logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex) causing **stackoverflow and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
with repeatative call of following stacktrace. it is happening randomly on our application.
**Log4j2 version is 2.17.0**

```
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.handleLogMessageException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2225)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2208)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2159)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2142)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2058)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (AbstractLogger.java:1931)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2805)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.handleLogMessageException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2225)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2208)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2159)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2142)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:2017)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (AbstractLogger.java:1983)
  at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (Log4jLogger.java:319)
```

Lo4j2.xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
               packages="custom.appender">
    <Appenders>
        <Routing name="CustomRouting">
            <Routes pattern="${sys:pathToLogfile}">
                <Route>
                    <CustomRollingRandomAccessFile name="FILE"
                        fileName="${sys:pathToLogfile}/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                        filePattern="${sys:pathToLogfile}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
                        immediateFlush="true" append="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m | %X%n" />
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                            <Delete basePath="${sys:pathToLogfile}">
                                <IfFileName glob="//*.log.gz" />
                                <IfLastModified age="60d" />
                            </Delete>
                        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                    </CustomRollingRandomAccessFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>      
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m | %X%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ERROR" includeLocation="true" >            
            <AppenderRef ref="CustomRouting">
                <ThreadContextMapFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT">
                    <KeyValuePair key="Dir" value="customval" />
                </ThreadContextMapFilter>
            </AppenderRef>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running out of memory, it's totally random which operation will run into this condition. It could be logging, or it could be anything else.

You'll have to monitor your application and either

- provide more memory (if it shows that the allocated memory is not enough)
- or fix a memory leak. Proper monitoring will show you the memory use over time.

If memory use only ever goes up (and garbage collection doesn't bring it down to a constantly low level), chances are you have a memory leak. Allocating more memory in that case *might* buy you some time (e.g. you might be able to go two weeks), but it'll not fix the issue.

But there's most likely nothing wrong with logging. It just is the operation that happens to run when memory runs out due to some other faulty component, or low allocated resources.

**Edit:** Somehow I've missed the stackoverflow part of your question - likely the "once a week" misled me to preliminary conclusion.

Please edit your question with more information - e.g. how did you configure your logging, and if it always happens at the same time, is there some scheduled event (e.g. log rotation, or a scheduled-once-a-week-job) at that time?

If you're absolutely positive that this is a log4j-related problem, my assumption is that it's somewhere in the (unprovided) log4j-configuration, rather than a programming issue.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf,
Actually if there is no issue in log4j then why is it recursively calling the stack mention in my post.
Actually It is calling tryLogMessage() method of org\apache\logging\log4j\spi\AbstractLogger.java if you look at the method code snippet it is calling log() method catching Exception and again calling method handleLogMessageException() recursively calling method.
`private void tryLogMessage() {
        try {
            log(level, marker, fqcn, location, msg, throwable);
        } catch (final Exception e) {handleLogMessageException(e, fqcn, msg);} }`

Comment: @RupeshSawaliya, do you have any messages on your application's `stderr`? My guess is: the `OutOfMemoryException` causes other `OutOfMemoryException`'s to be generated during the logging process and those are also logged. Hence the recursion.

Comment: @Olaf Kock
I have updated the question with log4j2  configuration.